# YAML File From JSON

Tags: javascript, json, yaml, cuttle

I am trying to create a yaml file from a json file that will be used for cuttle rate limiting and will look something like this (https://github.com/mrkschan/cuttle/blob/master/cuttle.yml). This is the code that I have to convert the json file. (node-yaml: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-yaml)

```
const yaml = require('node-yaml');
const test = require('./test.json');

let converted = yaml.dump(test);
console.log(converted);
```

Here is the test.json file.

```
{
"zones": 
    [ 
        { 
            "host": "*", 
            "shared": true, 
            "control": "rps", 
            "rate": 2 
        }, 
        { 
            "host": "github.com", 
            "shared": false, 
            "control": "rpm", 
            "rate": 10
        }
    ] 
}
```

The output that I get is this.

```
zones:
  - host: '*'
    shared: true
    control: rps
    rate: 2
  - host: github.com
    shared: false
    control: rpm
    rate: 10
```

It's super close to what I want to output except for the fact that github.com is not "github.com". If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know!

Comment: What does mean `github.com is not "github.com"` ?

Comment: One is double quoted, one is not

Answer (score 0):

From [yaml_format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html):
*Strings in YAML can be wrapped both in single and double quotes. In some cases, they can also be unquoted*.

So `github.com` string value in yaml output is correctly unquoted, and `*` string value in yaml output is correctly quoted.

If you expect formally correct yaml format you are done.
If you expect some different format you should formally define it.

Comment: IIRC there are implementation problems exactly with parsing strings in Symfony. In any event Symfony implements a subset of the YAML specification, so quoting its documentation doesn't help to make your answer more thrustworthy, e.g. quoting the official YAML specification would. In addition to that node-yaml has no such subset restrictions as Symfony's YAML has: it supports the full YAML 1.2 spec

Answer (score 0):

In YAML `github.com` doesn't need quotes. With or without it, it represents the same scalar value.

But since YAML is a superset of JSON your `test.json` file already **is** perfectly fine YAML, and there is absolutely no need to parse it (using a JSON or YAML library) and then dump to YAML. The **only** thing your program needs to do is copy (or rename) `test.json` to `test.yaml` and you are done.

As a side note: Your link points to a `cuttle.yml`, there is no explanation what restrictions they have to use a `.yml` extension. The recommended extension for YAML files, as posted on the [official FAQ on yaml.org](https://yaml.org/faq.html), has been `.yaml` since Sep. 2006.

Comment: So you are saying that if I change my file name to have a .yaml extension, it will be configurable with cuttle and work fine?

Comment: Since node-yaml is a YAML 1.2 parser, and YAML 1.2 is a superset: yes. See [Relation to YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759572) in the YAML 1.2 specification

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. If I simply need to rename, I wouldn't be using node-yaml at all. So in that case it won't be configurable with cuttle?

Comment: Yes you would not need node-yaml at all. Any program that uses a library that was updated to the 2009 spec for YAML 1.2 can read that file. I don't understand where "it" refers to in your last statement and why there is a question mark after a non-interrogative sentence. That you are confused doesn't mean that JSON is not a YAML subset.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's how I talk which may be a bit confusing. Essentially I was asking if the json file would work with cuttle as a replacement for yaml.

Comment: cuttle is using gopkg.in/yaml.v2 that might not be a **full** YAML 1.2 implementation (it doesn't support multi-document files), but I see no reason why it shouldn't parse those JSON files as is.